# How to flush buffer early in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 and I want to flush the buffer early (between head and response) as it is one of the best practices to improve performance. In this [article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html) BalusC shows how to do in in a JSP page (`<% response.getWriter().flush(); %>`), but I'm using xhtml pages.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks! 
Damian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `<h:head>` in JSF2, then you can **in theory** do this by explicitly flushing the underlying servlet output stream in the `encodeEnd()` method of the `Renderer` associated with the component.

There are basically two ways to implement a custom renderer. If you want to be implementation independent, then you have write the entire `Renderer` yourself which is a piece of work (although for a simple HTML `<head>` element this is not that hard). You can also choose to be implementation specific so that you end up with a simpler custom `Renderer` implementation. Assuming that you're using Mojarra, then you just have to extend the `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer`.

E.g.

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer;

public class FlushedHeadRenderer extends HeadRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        super.encodeEnd(context, component);
        context.getExternalContext().getResponseOutputWriter().flush(); // Forces flush.
    }

}
```

which you then register as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.FlushedHeadRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

However, this approach has caveats. JSF does not have the opportunity anymore to create a session whenever necessary, or to handle any exception as error page whenever an exception is been thrown in midst of rendering the view. **I would not recommend this approach for JSF**.

Answer (score 1):

If using myFaces, there is a context param you can set in your web.xml like below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EARLY_FLUSH_ENABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```