# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Tags: maven, jsf, factory, illegalstateexception

I want to migrate from jsf 2.1 to 2.2 but I can not run my server (Tomcat) to couse of the following error:
(I'm yours to inform you that I used [Hibernate + Spring + JSF] in project Maven)

```
`Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@37fc34bf: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Apr 25 19:38:18 WEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml]
Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@37fc34bf]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55251cfd
Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55251cfd: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1837 ms
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager copyInjectionProviderFromFacesContext
Grave: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
Grave: L’application n’a pas été initialisée correctement au démarrage. Impossible de localiser la Fabrique : javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:220)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1488)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:523)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initStartupFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:495)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
Grave: L’application n’a pas été initialisée correctement au démarrage. Impossible de localiser la Fabrique : javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:220)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1488)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:523)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initStartupFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:495)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error listenerStart
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/app] suite aux erreurs précédentes
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
Grave: L’application n’a pas été initialisée correctement au démarrage. Impossible de localiser la Fabrique : javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) à l'instance de classe d'écoute org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:220)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1488)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:523)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initShutdownFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:505)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
Grave: L’application n’a pas été initialisée correctement au démarrage. Impossible de localiser la Fabrique : javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte détruit (context destroyed) à l'instance de classe d'écoute org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:220)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1488)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._createFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:523)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initShutdownFacesContext(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:505)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

avr. 25, 2014 7:38:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Infos: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@37fc34bf: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Apr 25 19:38:18 WEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55251cfd: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:20 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
Grave: The web application [/app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1] (value [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1@a756d09]) and a value of type [org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupFacesContextImpl] (value [org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.StartupFacesContextImpl@23496f3c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8182"]
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8209"]
avr. 25, 2014 7:38:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Infos: Server startup in 12752 ms
`
```

this my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>app</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/faces-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.aspx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>excite-bike</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>1000000</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Extensions Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

this is my :pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project-app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <name>app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- les proprietés 3.1.4 -->
    <properties>
        <logback.version>0.9.15</logback.version>
        <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
        <struts2.version>2.2.1.1</struts2.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <env>LOCAL</env>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-bean-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MyFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- primafaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Junit 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple 
            backend -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers between cglib and 
            javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version> <!-- 3.4.GA -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySql jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- javax.servlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- javax.servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ajouter upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>





        <!-- ajouter upload -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax</groupId>
          <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
          <version>7.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.5</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.1</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- filtrage des ressources -->

    <!-- <resources> -->
    <!-- <resource> -->
    <!-- <directory>src/main/resources</directory> -->
    <!-- <filtering>true</filtering> -->
    <!-- </resource> -->
    <!-- </resources> -->
    <!-- <filters> -->
    <!-- <filter>src/main/filters/${env}.properties</filter> -->
    <!-- </filters> -->

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-repository</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
          <id>jvnet-nexus-snapshots</id>
          <name>jvnet-nexus-snapshots</name>
          <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

this is my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See @BalusC answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897900/could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-application-applicationfactory-jav) about the same problem. You have two jsf implementations in your `pom.xml`: myfaces and mojarra. So myfaces is conflicting with mojarra. Remove one of them

```
<!-- MyFaces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<!-- Mojarra -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```